# React prevstate usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Cell` component and when I click on it I want some popup window named `ChangeParamWindow` to appear. `ChangeParamWindow` has 2 buttons and if any of them was clicked I want to refresh value in the `Cell` to refresh from the popup input & `ChangeParamWindow` change its display to `none` if it is `block`  (for hiding block). It hides itself succesfully only one time, but never again. I am pretty sure that using prevState somehow wrong, but could abybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
class ChangeParamWindow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      placeholder: "Param...",
      maxlength  : 100,
      inputType  : "text",
      type       : "any",  // number or string. (for restritions)
      value      : null,
      outline    : "none",
      position   : "absolute",
      display    : "block"
    }
    this.inputId = "small-window-input-id"
  }
  onClose(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let value = document.getElementById(this.inputId).value
    console.log("new value is", value)

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      display : (prevState.display == "none") ? "display" : "none", // TODO ???
      value   : value
    }))
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div
        style={{
            display  : this.state.display,
            position : this.state.position,
            outline  : this.state.outline,
            left     : this.props.x,
            top      : this.props.y
        }}
        >
          <input
              id={this.inputId}
              maxLength={this.state.maxlength}
              type={this.state.inputType}
              placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
          />
          <input
              onClick={ this.onClose }
              type="submit"
              value="ok"
          />
          <input
              onClick={this.onClose }
              type="submit"
              value="cancel"
          />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Cell extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value   : null,
      type    : "any",
      noValue : "..."
    }
  }
  openChangeParamWindow(x, y) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ChangeParamWindow
          x={x}
          y={y}
        />,
        document.getElementById("change-param-window")
    )
  }
  isNumberValid() {

  }
  isStringValid() {

  }
  render() {
    let value = (this.state.value == null) ? this.state.noValue : this.state.value;
    return (
      <div
          className="cell"
          onClick={event => {
            this.openChangeParamWindow(event.clientX, event.clientY)
          }}
      >
        {value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Cell />,
    document.getElementById('init-cell')
);
```

```css
.cell {
    background:grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border:0;
    transition: 0.25s;
    width:40px;
    height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.cell:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="change-param-window"></div>
<div id="init-cell"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly do not want to be using `ReactDOM.render` twice here. You should be rendering your app's root component with `ReactDOM.render`, but after that, if you want to render something outside the hierarchy of your component tree, you'll want to use [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). The docs here should sort you out. If you're still in need of help, I can dig deeper.

Comment: I am a newbie to react. Could you explain why should I use portals, instead the way I do it now? Is there any difference or I cannot do some stuff using method I use now comparing to portals?

Comment: The main reason can be quoted from the docs:


"Even though a portal can be anywhere in the DOM tree, it behaves like a normal React child in every other way. Features like context work exactly the same regardless of whether the child is a portal, as the portal still exists in the React tree regardless of position in the DOM tree."

When you use `ReactDOM.render` you're creating a whole new React Tree. Since you want to pass data/events between `<ChangeParamWindow>` and `<Cell>`, Portals are the best choice.

Comment: Can I ask a question, though? Are you sure you need to render this `ChangeParamWindow` component as a separate element that is somewhere else in the DOM entirely?

Comment: Not sure, I am new to React and I cannot say that I am sure about most things I do, but I strive to google best solutions for my purposes. Just created what I want using portals, thank your for advice, I will accept it because this approach is easy and officially documented